# Why have we 2 tags: England vs England and Wales?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Correct me if [Wikipedia's wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_law#Application_of_English_law_to_Wales), but England and Wales are the same jurisdiction?

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england-and-wales

[Tom Bolam](https://www.fladgate.com/lawyer/tom-bolam/), Senior Associate (as of 1-29-2018), Fladgate (Solicitors' firm):

> [United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland (to give it its full name) has three separate and distinct legal systems: (i) Scotland; (ii) England and Wales; and (iii) Northern Ireland.](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=8f9476e8-b712-4726-b675-21463a3355e9)

Neil Guthrie [DPhil English (Oxon), LLB (Toronto)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/guthrieneil/).  [*Guthrie’s Guide to Better Legal Writing*  (2017)](https://www.amazon.ca/Guthries-Guide-Better-Legal-Writing/dp/1552214729). p. 95.

[image]

Comment: It seems to me the best thing would be to synonymize 'england' to be part of 'england-and wales'; this would need more votes.

Comment: Somebody needs to propose the synonym first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good catch: I just merged and made [england](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england) a synonym for [england-and-wales](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/england-and-wales).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this may not be a good catch. There is law which is different between England and Wales (although most criminal law is indeed "England & Wales").

There are currently 34 [Acts of the National Assembly for Wales](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/anaw) which apply only to Wales. There are more than 200 [pieces of legislation which apply exclusively to England](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/=england), most of which admittedly are Measures for the Church of England.

There should really be three tags, England & Wales, England, and Wales.

Comment: <Facepalm> ...  :(

Comment: Or maybe one tag: England and/or Wales.

Comment: Tags should disambiguate: they should not add unclarity.